# Highlighting correct path with Wordpress Nav_Menu function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, menuitem, relative-path, breadcrumbs

I have created a WordPress site for a client, in which you filter through the navigation menu (set-up in appearance->menu) by revealing hidden items (unordered lists with class "sub-menu (generated through WordPress menu function)). 
There are three hierarchal tiers; Pages>custom-links>Posts. When the page is clicked, the children (custom-links) are revealed, when a custom link is clicked, the children posts are revealed.
Then, when you are on a post, the path taken is highlighted in the navigation. 
This is done through css and current/parent/ancestor classes generated with the wp_nav_menu function. 
The mark-up generated by the wp_nav_menu function is this:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-2" class="main_menu"><li id="menu-item-155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-155"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?page_id=60">Design</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-152" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-152"><a href="#DesignCat1">#DesignCat1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-207" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-207"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=113">DesignC1P1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-206" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-206"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=115">DesignC1P2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-153"><a href="#DesignCat2">#DesignCat2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-144"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=117">DesignC2P1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-143"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=119">DesignC2P2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-156" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-156"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?page_id=62">Research</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-149"><a href="#">#ResearchCat1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-205" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-205"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=121">ResearchC1P1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-204" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-204"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=123">ResearchC1P2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-150"><a href="#">#ResearchCat2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-140"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=125">ResearchC2P1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-139"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=127">ResearchC2P2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The current page being "DesignC1P1", it's assigned a class of "current-menu-item", its parent (a custom link(#DesignCat1)) assigned "current-menu-parent" and its ancestor (a page(Design)) assigned "current-menu-ancestor". So, with CSS I do:

```
.current-menu-item > .sub-menu, .current-menu-parent > .sub-menu, .current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu  {
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline;
}


.current-menu-item > a, .current-menu-parent > a, .current-menu-ancestor > a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Which works well, it keeps all the relevant menu items visible and highlighted in black.

My issue is that my client has specifically asked for posts to be in more than one location in the menu, IE the same post could be under Design page and Research Page, or under two different custom-links in design/research. That means the same mark up is generated for the two item locations, and both paths are shown rather than the path taken. Here is what the generated code with the "Same Post" under #DesignCat1 and #ResearchCat1 would look like:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-2" class="main_menu"><li id="menu-item-155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-155"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?page_id=60">Design</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-152" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-152"><a href="#DesignCat1">#DesignCat1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-202" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-202"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=193">Same Post</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-153"><a href="#DesignCat2">#DesignCat2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-144"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=117">DesignC2P1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-143"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=119">DesignC2P2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-156" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-156"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?page_id=62">Research</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-149"><a href="#">#ResearchCat1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-203" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-203"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=193">Same Post</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-150"><a href="#">#ResearchCat2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-140"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=125">ResearchC2P1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-139"><a href="http://localhost:8888/?p=127">ResearchC2P2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas how to highlight only the path taken, rather than both? I know HTML,CSS and a bit of java, not so good with PHP! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It may come from a jQuery script which add "current-menu-item" class when you click on an item. Are you familar with JS/jQuery ? :)

Comment: hey, thanks for the comment. It may do, I had a quick look through relevant js files in wordpress - but I couldn't see anything. I know some Javascript/Jquery but really only front end stuff. If it does use js/jq somewhere to add the "current-menu-item" and relative parents/ancestors, how can I use this to form a solution?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that's a JQ part. I think it's while generating the menu list... So when you are on a page, PHP checks if this page is in the menu list... So there is no way to remember which path user used... You would have to store it somewhere (cookie or session ?) and use it while generating the page... It may be tricky...

Comment: Yeah I had a similar suggestion, but I think that's beyond me. I wouldn't really know where to begin with that! Wanted to know if there was another way around it. Thank you for your help.